# how to organize nodejs export in file structure but without create file with the same structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs

I have a library that has file structure like this

```
root
|-- index.js
|-----folder1
        |---- module a
....
.... other modules that under other folders
```

I don't want consumer of the library to import module a like this

```
import {...} from "mylibrary/folder1/moudleAIndex"
```

will be good if developer can just do

```
import {...} from "mylibrary/moduleA"
```

is there a way to do above without changing my current file structure?

Comment: if you have a file `index.js` in your folder1, then `import {...} from "mylibrary/folder1"` should work fine. In such case you would rename your folder1 to moduleA to get the syntax you want.

Comment: You can have a root file with multiple exports (kinda like a proxy but for exporting file) most library do that. The dev will import what he needs from that file, and your project can change it’s file structure as you wish.

Comment: @BorisCharpentier can you provide a sample?

Comment: @BorisCharpentier https://codesandbox.io/s/9oq05mjzr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `mylibrary/moduleA.js` file with the content:

```
import * as moduleA from './folder1/moudleAIndex';
export moduleA;
```

Comment: i guess this is the only way. canot do it without create new file